# Sharepoint Active directory forms authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory, ldap, forms-authentication

I am devloping a sharepoint website in Forms authentication mode. I am trying to authenticate myself/ my company users against company's active directory. 
The ldap path I received from my technical team is

> LDAP://infinmumcfac.inf.com
>   OU=Infotech,DC=inf,DC=com

I got this piece of code from microsoft site.

```
<membership defaultProvider="LdapMembershipProvider"> 
<providers> 
<add 
name="LdapMembership" 
type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C" 
server="DC"  
 port="389" 
useSSL="false" 
userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
userContainer="CN=Users,DC=userName,DC=local"  
userObjectClass="person" 
userFilter="(|(ObjectCategory=group)(ObjectClass=person))" 
scope="Subtree" 
otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" 
/> 
</providers> 
</membership>
```

The site asked me to change the Server and Usercontainer attribute. I have modified the code to

```
<membership defaultProvider="LdapMembershipProvider"> 
<providers> 
<add 
name="LdapMembership" 
type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C" 
server=” infinmumcfac.inf.com”
port="389" 
useSSL="false" 
userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
userContainer=" OU=Infotech,DC=inf,DC=com "   
userObjectClass="person" 
userFilter="(|(ObjectCategory=group)(ObjectClass=person))" 
scope="Subtree" 
otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" 
/> 
</providers> 
</membership>
```

I placed this code in web.config file of central administration site and my sharepoint website . I am still facing login issues.
Any help or insight would be highly grateful.Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set up zones, authentication providers and alternate access mappings in central administration.

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the reply. I am still  not very clear. Just confirming, is my modified piece of code correct???
If it is so...cool.
Please guide me for the rest of steps..
Thanks.

Comment: The web.config code looks correct, but isn't enough to make SharePoint use that provider. Take a look at steps 5-7 on http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/windows-forms/configuring-forms-authentication-in-sharepoint-2007/